# Pausing background music in IOS

Tags: ios, music.app

What can make the IOS Music app pause when the pause icon is not visible?

I was using an iPad app that has no sound and the song I was playing stopped.  No fingers (nor anything else) was near any of the buttons.  Brought Music to the foreground, and it was definitely paused.

Notification sounds (alarms, e-mail, timers, etc.) can interrupt Music, but they only reduce the volume, and not permanently.  Also, none of those happened.

Comment: First line of second paragraph.  That app actually has sound effects, BUT they are turned off, AND the documentation says if they are on but music is playing, they will not interrupt.  I've had the game for a long time, and when I first got it, I had the sound on and verified that it never interrupted music.  I do have a song that has some sort of corruption that makes Music pause, but that one is not the one that paused.

Comment: Which app/game is it? Some apps/games use illegally background audio to keep their app in the background running. Maybe it's since a recent update?

Comment: Words With Friends.   Come to think of it, it does occasional play a video ad after a turn, but that's the only time it makes sound, and that didn't happen then.  It's last update was quite a few days ago and I use it every day.